# A local run of expect script works fine, but hangs when ran through gitlab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, expect, spawn

I'm writing an expect file to connect to handle the interaction with the remote device by using a script that looks something like the following, and I am facing a few problems with it. Mainly, when I run the script stand-alone or interactively (on a runner), it works as I wish, but when I plug in the code for a testing using the Gitlab CI on one of the runners, it has the following problems:

1. the command `spawn /usr/bin/scp $rsaFile
   remote:/var/root/id_rsa.pub` doesn't seem to show up in the CI log
   (though the first `spawn /usr/bin/ssh remote` command shows up) - I
   suspect it's not being called at all.
2. The same *spawn* command persistently gives me the following message until the script stops executing at the next *interact* command: `"Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n"`
3. *interact* complains that `spawn id exp0 not open` (which I assume may be because scp command not working properly)

Here's the code:

```
spawn /usr/bin/ssh remote

expect {
    -re ".*assword:.*" {
        exp_send "password\r"; 
        exp_continue
    }
    -re ".*sh.*" {
        exp_send "mount -uw /\r";
        exp_send "nvram -somecommand"
        exp_send "exit\r"
    }
}

interact

# Copy over the key
set rsaFile "/var/root/Resources/id_rsa.pub"
spawn /usr/bin/scp $rsaFile remote:/var/root/id_rsa.pub;

expect {
    # 1&2 were added to the original script for debugging purposes
    -re "^id_rsa.pub.*" { #1: output I'd expect in case of successful scp
        exp_send "exit\r"
    }
    -re ".*assword:.*" {
        exp_send "password\r";
        exp_send "exit\r"
    }
    -re "Warning:.*Warning.*Warning.*" { #2: to debug the expect hanging
        exp_send "exit\r"
    }
}

interact;
```

Here's the error msg (expect is on debug mode):

```
spawn /usr/bin/ssh remote

parent: waiting for sync byte

parent: telling child to go ahead

parent: now unsynchronized from child

spawn: returns {24373}

Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*assword:.*' is '*assword:*'. Activating booster.
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*sh.*' is '*sh*'. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

".*sh.*"? Gate "*sh*"? gate=no

Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

expect: does "Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

".*sh.*"? Gate "*sh*"? gate=no

root@fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4's password: 

expect: does "Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\nroot@fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4's password: " (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=yes re=yes

expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\nroot@fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4's password: "

expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"

expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\nroot@fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4's password: "

send: sending "password\r" to { exp6 }

expect: continuing expect

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

".*sh.*"? Gate "*sh*"? gate=no

expect: does "\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

".*sh.*"? Gate "*sh*"? gate=no

expect: does "\r\n\u001b[?1034h" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

".*sh.*"? Gate "*sh*"? gate=no

-sh-3.2# 

expect: does "\r\n\u001b[?1034h-sh-3.2# " (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

".*sh.*"? Gate "*sh*"? gate=yes re=yes

expect: set expect_out(0,string) "\r\n\u001b[?1034h-sh-3.2# "

expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"

expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n\u001b[?1034h-sh-3.2# "

send: sending "mount -uw /\r" to { exp6 }

send: sending "nvram -some-command" to { exp6 }

send: sending "exit\r" to { exp6 }

interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0

parent: waiting for sync byte

parent: telling child to go ahead

parent: now unsynchronized from child

spawn: returns {24376}

Gate keeper glob pattern for '^id_rsa.pub.*' is 'id_rsa?pub*'. Activating booster.
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*assword:.*' is '*assword:*'. Activating booster.
Gate keeper glob pattern for 'Warning:.*Warning.*Warning.*' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp1) match regular expression "^id_rsa.pub.*"? Gate "id_rsa?pub*"? gate=no

".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

"Warning:.*Warning.*Warning.*"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp1) match regular expression "^id_rsa.pub.*"? Gate "id_rsa?pub*"? gate=no

".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

"Warning:.*Warning.*Warning.*"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\nWarning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\r\n\r\n" (spawn_id exp1) match regular expression "^id_rsa.pub.*"? Gate "id_rsa?pub*"? gate=no

".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

"Warning:.*Warning.*Warning.*"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no

expect: does "Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\nWarning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\r\n\r\nWarning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n" (spawn_id exp1) match regular expression "^id_rsa.pub.*"? Gate "id_rsa?pub*"? gate=no

".*assword:.*"? Gate "*assword:*"? gate=no

"Warning:.*Warning.*Warning.*"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=yes

expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\nWarning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\r\n\r\nWarning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"

expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp1"

expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Warning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\nWarning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\r\n\r\nWarning: Permanently added 'fe80::cccc:48ff:fe33:3344%en4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"

send: sending "exit\r" to { exp1 }

interact: spawn id exp0 not open
    while executing
"interact"
    (file "./Resources/Setup.command" line 44)

ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance
BTW- the problem was annoying enough for me to figure out, as this is my very first post to stack overflow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
spawn /usr/bin/ssh remote

expect {
    -re ".*assword:.*" {
        exp_send "password\r";
        exp_continue
    }
    -re ".*-sh-.*" {
        exp_send "mount -uw /; nvram -somecommand; exit\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    eof {}
}
wait

set rsaFile "/var/root/Resources/id_rsa.pub"
spawn /usr/bin/scp $rsaFile remote:/var/root/id_rsa.pub;

expect {
    -re ".*assword:.*" {
        exp_send "password\r";
        exp_continue
    }
    eof {}
}
wait
```

Your `interact` may fail because at that time the *spawn*ed process may have already exited and obviously it cannot *interact* with a *dead* process.

For your script, my `expect eof` basically have the same effect with your `interact`. They all wait for the *spawn*ed process to finish. The difference here is timing. And `expect eof` just does not generate error when the *spawn*ed process exits.

Comment: wow... you are amazing! Can you explain your logic behind the changes you've made? why does using eof {} then wait construct work better than interact?